# GoogleAds conversion action with custom value

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm try to create new conversion action that the value in UI will be "**Use different values for each conversion**"

I'm using `add_conversion_action.py` from example.
In the value_settings I set:

```
value_settings.default_value = 0.0
value_settings.always_use_default_value = True
```

But in the UI I got "**Don't use a value for this conversion action (not recommended)**"

I try to look for answer on developers.google but all looks fine.

Thanks!

The code from example:

```
# [START add_conversion_action]
def main(client, customer_id):
    conversion_action_service = client.get_service("ConversionActionService")

    # Create the operation.
    conversion_action_operation = client.get_type("ConversionActionOperation")

    # Create conversion action.
    conversion_action = conversion_action_operation.create
    conversion_action.name = f"Earth to Mars Cruises Conversion {uuid.uuid4()}"
    conversion_action.type_ = (
        client.enums.ConversionActionTypeEnum.UPLOAD_CLICKS
    )
    conversion_action.category = (
        client.enums.ConversionActionCategoryEnum.DEFAULT
    )
    conversion_action.status = client.enums.ConversionActionStatusEnum.ENABLED
    conversion_action.view_through_lookback_window_days = 15

    # Create a value settings object.
    value_settings = conversion_action.value_settings
    value_settings.default_value = 0.0
    value_settings.always_use_default_value = True

    # Add the conversion action.
    conversion_action_response = (
        conversion_action_service.mutate_conversion_actions(
            customer_id=customer_id,
            operations=[conversion_action_operation],
        )
    )

    print(
        "Created conversion action "
        f'"{conversion_action_response.results[0].resource_name}".'
    )
    # [END add_conversion_action]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you used

```
value_settings.default_value = 0.0
value_settings.always_use_default_value = True
```

To set "Use different values for each conversion", value_settings.always_use_default_value must be False.

`value_settings.always_use_default_value = False`